# How to instantiate a FormFile Object?

Tags: java, file

i have a String with a path of my file and i want to instancie a `new FormFile` with this String. It's possible ..?

My code:

```
    public ArrayList<FormFile> getFilesFromFolder(String path) {
  File file = new File(path);
  ArrayList<FormFile> vFiles = new ArrayList<FormFile>();

  if (file.exists()) {

   File[] files = file.listFiles();
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].isFile()) {
     vFiles.add((FormFile) files[i]);
    }
   }
  } else {
   vFiles = null;
  }
  return vFiles;
 }
```

but i have an error in this line `vFiles.add((FormFile) files[i]);`

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.io.File cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile

Answer (score 1):

`FormFile` is an interface (can't be instantiated). Look at an implementation of this interface, like `CommonsMultipartRequestHandler.CommonsFormFile`. This one has a constructor and can be created for a `FileItem` (`DiskFileItem`)  which represents a file.

Comment: read the javaDoc for those classes - it's all explained. If you don't have it: google for 'docjar FormFile' to access an online javaDoc.

Comment: when i do this 
DiskFile diskFile = new DiskFile(files[i].getPath());
i have the path of my file but i not have the content of my file

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing because you create a new `File` object, but you try to cast it to a `FormFile`.
A `FormFile` is an interface, so it can't be instantiated directly. It looks like you need a `DiskFile`, and it would be `new DiskFile(path)`.